# How to build and query a database of all CS:GO items

Tags: postgresql, steam-web-api

So as part of a uni project I'm trying to make a demo website that allows users to display items from their inventory that they wish to sell. It's not that serious of a project, but I do want to make it as robust as possible.

I figured I would need a way for users to search for items that they wish to buy, so I will need to store all CS:GO items in a database. One solution I found is steamapis which has a [Market API](https://steamapis.com/docs/market#items) that "Returns price details for all monitored items in our database that belong to the specified application". This seems useful as it means I can also exclude junk items (e.g., items with a mean sale price of < $0.25). The idea would be to build a database table like below:

| Column | Type | Details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID | INT AUTO_INCREMENT | Primary Key |
| Name | VARCHAR |  |
| Rarity | INT |  |

This would allow me to create a search field that loads results as you type, and correctly displays the text colour based on the Rarity. The response example returns `border_color` which it seems I may be able to derive the Rarity ("Restricted", etc.,) from? There's also `market_name` for the Name column.

However, I also need a way for users to be able to post items from their inventories. It seems like I can add ["Login with Steam" via OpenID 2.0](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/auth#website). Then I can verify they own the account and retrieve their Steam64 ID, which I can use to retrieve their inventory via the steamapis [Inventory API](https://steamapis.com/docs/steam#inventory).

The idea is to store a `UserPost` which contains a set of `UserPostItem`s. I thought that I could store the latter in a database table like:

| Column | Type | Details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID | INT AUTO_INCREMENT | Primary Key |
| ItemID | INT | Foreign Key (ID from above) |
| IconURL | VARCHAR |  |
| Exterior | INT |  |
| InspectURL | VARCHAR |  |
| TradeLock | INT |  |
| UserPostID | INT | Foreign Key |

The data returned from their API is the same as `https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/{Steam64 ID}/730/2?l=english&count=2000` so I can get all of this data. Though I am a little bit confused about how to parse the response in a way that lets me discern the quantities of items, as this seems to be oddly split between `assets` and `descriptions`. Storing the IconURL should help me avoid hosting any images myself.

So, now we have all the data we need to display the items in a user's post, including the image of that exact item, its inspect URL, exterior (BS/WW/FT/MW/FN), and hopefully rarity while maintaining a (hopefully) sane and vaguely ACID database.

One problem I encountered was retrieving specific item data such as float, paint ID and paint index, but this seems like a very difficult thing to solve and perhaps beyond the scope of this project.

Another issue I'm confused about is how exactly I link the items returned in the Inventory API query to those that exist in my database that has been populated as a result of the Market API. Each item in the Inventory API has a `classid`, `instanceid` and `assetid`. But the Market API only returns a `nameID` which I'm not sure the purpose of, and doesn't seem to be linked to any of the other IDs.

Additionally, I'm not sure if there's an efficient method that can be used to add newly released items to the database automatically. It also seems like the Market API method may have the limitation of not including items which are too expensive to be listed on the Steam Market.

Sorry for the long and somewhat rambly post, but I would really appreciate any guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to build the same database too and steam market api's missing many item, I suggest you parse from csgo game file or fastest method is :

> https://bymykel.github.io/CSGO-API/

But if you want other approach then try to web scraping those market site like buff163, swaps.gg, etc...

And about why there's different id in your csgo invetory because it use to mark and trade items